# Swift fetch request returns 0 results, even though there are clearly 192 results

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, interpolation, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I make my fetch request like so :

```
let pageFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Page")
let results = try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(pageFetchRequest)
```

Here, `results` will return `0 results {}`.

But I do this by itself :

```
managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(pageFetchRequest)
```

I get all 192 results. So long as I don't assign it to a variable such as `results`. Why is that? Does assigning it or using the method `try` prevent this from working?

**Update**

This is the full post. Notice how I'm using `managedObjectContext` twice for two different related requests. Maybe that's what is botching my results up?

```
    let managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext

    for item in items {
        let word = Word(chapter: Int(item.chapter)!, verse: Int(item.verse)!, sanskrit: item.sanskrit, english: item.english, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)

        // Assign the Page
        let pageFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Word")
        let chapterPred = NSPredicate(format: "(chapter = %d)", Int(item.chapter)!)
        let versePred   = NSPredicate(format: "(verse = %d)", Int(item.verse)!)
        pageFetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1
        pageFetchRequest.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type: .OrPredicateType, subpredicates: [chapterPred, versePred])

        do {
            let results = try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(pageFetchRequest)
            if let page = results.first as? NSManagedObject {
                word.setValue(page, forKey: "page")
            }

        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }

        do {
            try managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
```

Comment: How do you know you get 192 results when you don't assign to a variable?

Comment: @Macondo2Seattle From setting a debugger on that line and running the aformentioned line preceded by `po`

Comment: Do you have a catch block to detect errors?  per the documentation executeFetchRequest will return nil if there's an error.

Comment: @MathewSpolin yes the `try do catch` block is mandatory else the code won't run.  Sorry, it doesn't return `nil`. it returns `{}`. It doesn't error there either. It errors when the rest of my code seeks to inspect `results` but gets an empty array which it should never.

Comment: is results typed as [AnyObject]?  I'd usually cast something like this with `as! [Page]`

Comment: @MathewSpolin True, me too. But it's only returning `{}` so it wouldn't matter.

Comment: @MathewSpolin One idea I had was that maybe it's because I'm using `managedObjectContext` in other methods? They all draw from a `lazy var` in my `appDelegate`, but maybe I need to instantiate a new one?

Comment: You definitely need to use additional contexts if you're accessing them from other threads, or you'll get a crash.  I'm not sure that would cause this, but I'd look for some difference in how it runs when you're in the debugger - for example, if you were instantiating your core data context in a background thread and that wasn't finished, but in debug it has time to finish, etc.

Comment: @MathewSpolin This is all just to seed data when the app boots first time. So it makes sense that it's queued ( which I guess is what would happen if I use just one context ). I think you'll find someting I'm doing wrong if I post more code. I'll update above..

Answer (score 0):

So evidently the answer.. I think.. was to create a separate managedObjectContext that wouldn't be confused with the parent one.. Like so :

```
                let appDelegate          = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
                let secondManagedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
                let pageFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Page")Int(item.verse)!)
                pageFetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1
                pageFetchRequest.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type: .OrPredicateType, subpredicates: [chapterPred, versePred])
```

And then I had to also write this :

```
                do {
                    var results:[NSManagedObject]
                    results = try secondManagedContext.executeFetchRequest(pageFetchRequest) as! [Page]
                    if let page = results.first {
                        word.setValue(page, forKey: "page")
                    }
```